# Perl: Converting Formula To Perl Code What Should It Look Like?

Tags: perl, math

I have the following formula:

[image: Formula]

I tried to convert this to perl code and it looks like this:

```
$stuck = (360 / $pi2);
$stuck2 = sin($stuck * $Eccent * $M);
```

Where $Eccent = 0.016713 and $M = 202.065469250756 and $pi2 = 3.1415927

I get -0.542630163200668

And the answer should be: -0.719461

Any help would be appreciated as I don't have a clue what it should look like!

Comment: Is that supposed to say `(360/pi) * e * sin M`? Because that is not what your Perl code says, it says `sin( (360/pi) * e * M)`.

Comment: Why is the var holding pi named `$pi2`? I would expect that to contain 2π

Comment: Because $pi was in use with more digits. The book only called for the first 8 digits of pi. Thus, $pi2 was a shorter version of $pi. Just working out examples in a book, not production code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula takes the sine of M, nothing else.

```perl
use Math::Trig qw( pi );

my $Ec = 360 / pi * $e * sin($M);
```

There's a catch: Your value of M is in degrees, while [`sin`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sin) expects radians.

```perl
use Math::Trig qw( pi deg2rad );

my $Ec = 360 / pi * $e * sin(deg2rad($M));
```

This is equivalent to

```perl
use Math::Trig qw( deg2rad rad2deg );

my $Ec = rad2deg(2 * $e * sin(deg2rad($M)));
```